# I'm applying to transfer, and am filling out the Common App. Should I put Yes to disciplinary action?

Tags: transfer-student, disciplinary-action

I am currently applying to transfer colleges, and one of the questions the Common App asks is:

> Have you ever been found responsible for a disciplinary violation at any educational institution you have attended from the 9th grade (or the international equivalent) forward, whether related to academic misconduct or behavioral misconduct, that resulted in a disciplinary action? These actions could include, but are not limited to: probation, suspension, removal, dismissal, or expulsion from the institution.

Last April, I attended a dormroom party at which there was alcohol. This party was broken up by the RA. A lot of people fled, although I remained and cooperated. I was not drunk at the time.

The consequences were that I (along with a few others who remained) had to help plan a study session. At the time the hall coordinator told me that I was being placed on a probationary period of 3 months, and that if I wasn't caught attending another party within that 3 month period, the incident would be expunged from my record. There have been no other incidents since then, so I assume it was removed from my record.

Should I provide the details of this event to the Common App? Will this affect my chances of admission to another college?

Comment: [Common App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Application) _is an undergraduate college admission application that applicants may use to apply to any of more than 700 member colleges and universities ..._.

Comment: Pay attention to what they write "_These actions could include, but are not limited to: probation …_". You were placed on a probationary period of 3 months. Of course, you should mention the event. "_Will this affect my chances of admission to another college?_", that's up to the school you apply to.

Answer (score 1):

*This is likely to be closed, as we do not discuss undergraduate admissions here. Still, I'll take a stab at it.*

My understanding is that the whole point of "expungement" is to allow you to answer no to questions like this (unless the question specifically says to include expunged matters, as is sometimes the case, e.g., with law students). That's certainly the case when  [legal matters are expunged](http://www.legalaffairs.org/issues/January-February-2006/argument_schmoke_janfeb06.msp); I assume it is the same for in-house educational matters.

Still, I would recommend doing two things:

- Don't just "assume it was removed from my record" -- verify. Ask specifically whether other colleges who request your records will learn about this. Note, this is the kind of thing where it's easy for someone incompetent to just say "nope, it won't show up" to get you off the phone -- so keep asking questions until you're *really* satisfied. Getting an in-person meeting with a career employee (not a student worker) or the associate dean might be better than just calling on the phone and asking the receptionist.
- Contact the college you want to transfer to (anonymously, if you like) and ask whether they require you to disclose expunged matters on the common application.

  - If you can get it in writing that you don't have to (and save this
    reply in permanent storage), that should be sufficient to protect you
    if you are accused of anything later.
  - If you discuss this over the
    phone and are told not to report it, but can't get it in writing,
    send admissions an e-mail, in which you say "This is just to confirm
    what I discussed on the phone with Name at 8:00 AM on 12/1. As we
    discussed, expunged disciplinary matters need not be reported on the
    common application for transfer students. Please let me know if this
    is incorrect." Then retain this e-mail and their reply, if they send one.

As to the second part of your question, yes, if reported this could certainly adversely affect your changes of admission (and improperly concealing it could lead to your degree being revoked).